# How many bamboo sections should be added when Irrigating a plot with fertilizer?

Tags: takenoko

How many bamboo sections should be added to a plot with fertilizer when it gets irrigated for the first time? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two sections. The relevant rules on irrigation and fertilizer are:

> When a plot is irrigated for the first time, a section of bamboo of its color
> is added.
>
> A plot is eligible for this first shoot only once.

> Fertilizer increases the growth of bamboo on its plot. Each time the bamboo grows, two sections are added instead of one.

The rules say that when a plot is first irrigated that it gains one section of bamboo, and if a plot has fertilizer, that you add two sections instead of one. If you have a plot with fertilizer on it when it is first irrigated, then it would gain 2 (one for first irrigated, one more for gaining that shoot while fertilized)